# git: stage only new files

Tags: git, bash, scripting

When I have:

- dirty working directory,
- dirty staging area,
- and I copied some new files to the project,

how do I stage only the new ones?

```
git alias adduntracked=…
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This alias will respect your ignore patterns (builtin, global and per-directory, as described by the help for `git-ls-files --exclude-standard`). It will run at the top level of your tree.

```
[alias]
adduntracked=!git add $(git ls-files -o --exclude-standard)
```

Comment: Note that the `!` at the beginning of the alias makes it run at the top level of the tree. I rolled back the edit that removed this note from the answer after re-testing to verify that it really does work at the top level.

Comment: bstpierre, what do you mean by "work at the top level"?

Comment: **Note** this has issues for file names containing whitespace, `;rm -rf --no-preserve-root /;`, etc. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39489545/5353461) for a more robust solution.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to add all untracked files to the staging area:

```
git add .
```

I suppose that you want this, while keeping the unstaged changes to tracked files outside of the index.

```
git stash
git add . 
git stash apply
```

Would this help?

Comment: Thanks for this smart one :) What I was really looking for is: `for i in $(git ls-files -o) ; do git add $i ; done`

Comment: @takesin: You don't really need the for-loop: `git add $(git ls-files -o --exclude-standard)`. Note that I added `--exclude-standard` so that you don't end up adding files that you want to ignore.

Comment: Nice! Though I would say 'stash pop' to return your stashes to the original state.

Answer (score 3):

To allow for files with special characters in their names, use the following alias:

```
au = "!git ls-files -z -o --exclude-standard | xargs -0 git add; #"
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest something like this to copy:

```
for i in source/path ; do cp source/path/$i ./$i ; git add $i ; done
```

I'm not very well at shell scripting, but this would be an attempt

Comment: Seems pretty equal to `git add source/path` and doesn't filter untracked files from others.

Answer (score 0):

`git add -u` is what I use to stage untracked.

Edit: comments below have reminded me that its `git add .` that adds untracked (along with changed files, which I think is not what you want?). I use the `git add -u` to stage deleted files.

Comment: From git help: -u, --update
           Only match <filepattern> against already tracked files in the index rather than the working
           tree. That means that it will never stage new files, but that it will stage modified new
           contents of tracked files and that it will remove files from the index if the corresponding
           files in the working tree have been removed.

Comment: And precisely while I was pasting the text takeshin added, his reply appeared :)

Answer (score 0):

git add untracked

Comment: That's not actually a command, right? Do you mean `git add -i` then `4: add untracked`?

Answer (score 0):

git ls-files -o --exclude-standard | xargs git add

Answer (score 0):

A little improvement to the [solution of bstpierre](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707116/git-stage-only-new-files#answer-3709301), you can use this variation to be able to specify the directory in which you want to add files:

```
[alias]
  adduntracked="!f() { git add $(git ls-files -o --exclude-standard $@); }; f"
```