# Is there an option for "git add -?" to add only newly added files / removed files

Tags: git, git-add

`git status` gives me:

a list of added files

a list of modified files

a list of removed files

---

**What I know:**

`git add -A` --> all 3 lists

`git add .` ---> all 3 lists

`git add --ignore-removal .` ---> new and mod only

`git add -u` --> mod and deleted

**Question:**

`git add -??` --> new only

`git add -??` --> deleted only

`git add -??` --> new and deleted only

Comment: No there is no direct way to do this with a single command.  You'll have to do a little customer work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15761890/git-add-only-all-new-files-not-modified-files

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git: stage only new files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707116/git-stage-only-new-files)

Comment: To amend to that, `git ls-files` in addition to `-o` also supports `-d` (and more), so that should get you going.